# find the distance between line and point using dot product

Tags: calculus, vectors

Consider the line $L(t)=⟨2t−4,t−2,5t⟩$ and the point $P=
(4,2,1)$. How far is P from the line L?

I don't know how to find the distance between line and point, can anyone helps, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\vec{PL} \perp L(t)$, where $L\in L(t)$ or $L=L(t_0)$ such that $t_0$ gives the location of the point on the line closest to $P$.

*Note that L(t) is the line as a vector-valued function $L:R\rightarrow R^3$*

Now, let $\vec{PL(t)}=L(t)-P$ be the all of the vectors from the points of $L$ to the point $P$. Also let $\vec{N} = (2,1,5)$ be the normal vector to the line.

Thus,we need to find where the dot product between the potential distances and the normal vector to the line is equal to zero.
$$\begin{align}
\vec{PL(t)} \cdot \vec{N} \ 
&= (L(t)-P)\cdot \vec{N} \\
&=\langle 2t-8,t-4,5t-1\rangle \cdot\langle 2,1,5\rangle &=0 \\
&=2(2t-8)+1(t-4)+5(5t-1)&=0
\end{align}$$

This shows that $t_0=\frac{5}{6}$, which gives the perpendicular line:
$$\vec{PL}=PL(t_0) = \left\langle-\frac{19}{3},-\frac{19}{6},\frac{19}{6}\right\rangle $$
Them the magnitude of this perpendicular line is the shortest distance.
$$|\vec{PL}|=\frac{19}{6}\sqrt{2^2+1^2+1^2}=\frac{19}{\sqrt6}.$$
Done!

Comment: Where is sqrt(2^2+1^2+1^2) come from? thanks.

Comment: @kdhug886 $PL=\frac{19}{6}\|(-2,-1,1)\|=\frac{19}{6}\sqrt{(-2)^2+(-1)^2+1^2}$

Answer (score 0):

L(t)=⟨2t−4,t−2,5t⟩L(t)=⟨2t−4,t−2,5t⟩ and the point P=(4,2,1)

Let n be vector along L and K be vector along pQ, where Q  ∈ L

Hence K .n= (4,2,1)/||PQ|| •(2t-4,t-2,5t)/||L||=0
t=4/3

Q = ( -4/3 , -2/3 ,  20/3)

PQ= (16/3 , 8,3, -17/3)
|PQ|=finish it..

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, to find the minimum distance $d$ between a given line $L(t)=⟨2t−4,t−2,5t⟩$ and a point $P=(4,2,1)$, first, we know that the direction of $L(t)$ is $D=\langle 2,1,5 \rangle $.

We also know that the arbitrary point $P_0=(-4,-2,0)$ lies on the line for $t=0$.

Then, there is an arbitrary vector between $P$ and $L(t)$ given by this:
$$P-P_0=\vec{P_0P}=\langle 8,4,1\rangle.$$
Now, $\vec{P_0P}$ forms the hypotenuse of a right triangle with $d$ as the side opposite. Thus $d=|\vec{P_0P}|\sin(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{P_0P}$ and $L(t)$. This is equivalent to
$$d=\frac{\lvert \vec{P_0P} \ \times \ D \ \rvert}{\lvert D 
 \ \rvert}$$
Now, it is merely a matter of calculations:
$$\begin{align}
\vec{P_0P} \ \times \ D&= \langle 19, -38, 0\rangle \\
|\vec{P_0P} \ \times \ D|&= 19\sqrt5\\
|D \ |&=\sqrt{30} \\
d &= \frac{19}{\sqrt6} \\
\end{align}$$
$\square$